# link to asset csv file from within populate.rake

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csv, ruby-on-rails-4, rake, asset-pipeline

I need to load a list of foods from a csv file as part of populate.rake. This will make developing my site much faster.

I'm getting this error:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `path' for "./assets/food_db.csv":String
```

I have this method inside of populate.rake

```
def make_foods
  Food.import("/assets/food_db.csv")        
end
```

Inside food.rb

```
def self.import(file)
  CSV.foreach(file.path, headers: :true) do |row|
    self.create! row.to_hash
  end
end
```

How do I pass the file in properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were almost there!

```
# food.rb
def self.import(file_path) # you receive here the file path as a String
  CSV.foreach(file_path, headers: :true) do |row|
    self.create! row.to_hash
  end
end
```

Should work.

---

Also, I recommend you to use the full path of the file:

```
Food.import( Rails.root.join('app', 'assets', 'food_db.csv') )
# will be looking for a file in your application folder + `/app/assets/food_db.csv`
# For Ubuntu users, might look like this: `/home/<your_username>/<your_app_name>/app/assets/food_db.csv`
```

Comment: Thanks! I should have read the error more closely haha. Although now it still can't understand the path. I've tried a number of them. Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory - assets/food_db.csv

Comment: Great idea. I was looking for something like that. Although it still can't find the file. same error but with full path.

Comment: In this case I would use the terminal to go to the file's folder, then copy-paste the path to use it with `Rails.root`

Comment: I thought it was an incorrect path, but this is the real path and it still doesn't work: Food.import(Rails.root.join('app', 'lib', 'assets', 'food_db.csv'))... And ok I'll try that as well :)

Comment: (a quick way to test directly in your IRB console is to use `Dir.glob(Rails.root.join('lib', 'assets'))` and see the list of the available files in this directory) --- Oh @ninja08 I noticed that you used `Rails.root.join('app', 'lib', ...` but the `lib` folder is not inside the `app` folder, try this instead: `Rails.root.join('lib', 'assets', 'food_db.csv')`

Comment: Yeah the correct path is lib/assets/...etc as you mentioned last. Thanks for your help!!